# Scrapy: connection refused

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm receiving an error when trying to test scrapy installation:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.google.es
j2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.12.0.2536 started (bot: scrapybot)
2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, SpiderContext, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, CloseSpider
2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled scheduler middlewares: DuplicatesFilterMiddleware
2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpProxyMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2011-02-16 10:54:46+0100 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2011-02-16 10:54:47+0100 [default] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.google.es> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
2011-02-16 10:54:47+0100 [default] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.google.es> (failed 2 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
2011-02-16 10:54:47+0100 [default] DEBUG: Discarding <GET http://www.google.es> (failed 3 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
2011-02-16 10:54:47+0100 [default] ERROR: Error downloading <http://www.google.es>: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError'>: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
    ]
2011-02-16 10:54:47+0100 [scrapy] ERROR: Shell error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.

2011-02-16 10:54:47+0100 [default] INFO: Closing spider (shutdown)
2011-02-16 10:54:47+0100 [default] INFO: Spider closed (shutdown)
```

Versions:

- Scrapy 0.12.0.2536
- Python 2.6.6
- OS: Ubuntu 10.10

EDIT: I can reach it with my browser, wget, telnet google.es 80 and it happens with all the sites.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am also experiencing this when trying to use privoxy proxy with scrapy...

Answer (score 11):

Mission 1:
Scrapy will send a usergent with 'bot' in it. Sites might block based on user agent also.

Try over-riding USER_AGENT in settings.py

Eg: `USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.7'`

Mission 2:
Try giving a delay between request, to spoof that a human is sending the request.

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25
```

Mission 3:
If nothing works, install wireshark and see the difference in request header (or) post data 
while scrapy sends and when your browser sends.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is an issue with your network connection.

First of all, check your internet connection.

If you access net through proxy server, you should a piece of code into your scrapy project (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware)

Anyway, try upgrade your scrapy version.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error too. It turned out to be caused by port I was accessing was blocked by the firewall. My server blocked ports by default unless it is whitelisted.

Comment: How did you find that your server was blocking non-whitelisted ports?